# Backbone - Access a View's $el.attr outside of the ItemView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller, marionette, backbone-views

I have the following ItemView (there is no model associated with the view, it's a very basic "form" which has a submit or cancel and a single input field):

```
App.BasicForm = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "build/templates/basic-form.html",
    tagName: "div",
    attributes: {
        id: "some-id",
        style: "display: none;"
    },

    events: {
        "click button#bf-submit": "bfSubmit",
        "click button#bf-close": "bfClose"
    },

    bfSubmit: function() {
        var bfInputField= document.getElementById('bfSomeData').value;
    },

    bfClose: function() {
        this.$el.hide();
    }

});
```

So by default, this view is hidden (but is instantiated when App starts).

I want to have a button which, when clicked, simply changes the attribute style display to block.

I can do this easily like this:

```
document.getElementById('bfBasicFormDiv').style.display = "block";
```

However, I'd rather call the view's $el.attr and edit it there, something along the lines of:

```
App.BasicForm.$el.attr({style: "display: block;"});
```

However, this returns an undefined, and I can see no way of retrieving the attribute of the View (it's easy with models using .get()) but that doesn't hold for a view.

Thank you for any advice.

Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`App.BasicForm` is not an instance, so it doesn't hold an element. You need to initialize it and you will be able to reference the element with `$el`:

```
var basicForm = new App.BasicForm({
    el: document.getElementById('bfBasicFormDiv')
});
basicForm.$el.css({display: "block"});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to remove the "display: none;" on the ItemView then and just recreate it every time it's opened (and destroy it when they hit close)?

Comment: Oh, I see what you did. When I initially define the model I can use what you have, so later in the code I can refer to it as basicForm.$el

Comment: no, you do not destroy a view just to hide it. You can have methods on your view: `show` and `hide`, where you can define logic for showing and hiding, and then call them according to your required logic. The methods might simply update the `display` css property.

Comment: That makes more sense! I'll do that now and get back with the results

Comment: So I've added a show() and hide() to my view as suggested, where I tell it to edit the view's attribute, but I don't understand how to call this from outside... (this is the first time I've created a view without a model)

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle with your view that you try to run? I will try to help you to edit it to make it run.

Comment: Okay sure I'll start doing that now

Comment: This might take a while to create... I'll post the fiddle later tonight as I don't have the whole code base with me right now (the app itself is quite big, so I need work on all the code at once, e.g. the controller). Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Okay. Also note that jQuery has method `css` that you'd use instead of editing `style` attribute. Then jQuery also has `hide` and `show` methods that are shortcuts for hiding and showing an element by switching it's css `display` value. E.g. `view.$el.show()` will show the element and `view.$el.hide()` will hide it.

Comment: My plan was to keep them separate (them being jQuery and Backbone), but it seems Backbone.View depends on jQuery so no point in doing it my way... I have it working now, I was calling `new App.BasicForm` within a Module, so I just called it `Module.basicForm = new App.BasicForm` and refer to it as `App.Module.basicForm.$el.hide()`. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, Backbone relies on jQuery for DOM operations.